# Understanding method chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, chaining

I want method chaining to work, but it seems i'm not getting some concepts.

This:

```
$(".list").activeJS()
```

first has to use jQuery to get a HTMLElement nodelist and then it has to call the activeJS() function passing the nodelist.

```
var activeJS = function(item){

    alert(item) //nodelist


}
```

Now i get a TypeError: $(...).activeJS is not a function error in my console.

Thx,

Comment: [You should do some studying.](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a function callable from a jQuery object, you have to add it to the jQuery prototype object:

```
jQuery.fn.activeJS = function(item) {
  // ... whatever
};
```

Comment: How would i set this up as a reference to my function and still returning the jquery nodelist so i can alert the nodelist, as in my example above?

Comment: @kevinius jQuery plugin functions follow a certain convention. When called, `this` is bound to the jQuery object, and it's the responsibility of the plugin function to return the jQuery object if it's designed to be used in a chain. The page I linked in a comment under your question goes into details.

Comment: Hi, thx, i've read trough the tutorial but some of my questions are not answered. Like, how can i reference a function instead directly assigning a function to the prototype, while still passing in the jQuery object - jQuery.fn.activeJS = function(item){ activeJS(item)}

Comment: You can always write the function separately and then put a reference to it on a prototype, just as you can with any function. In other words, if you define function "myFunc", then you can make it a jQuery plugin with `jQuery.fn.myFunc = myFunc;`

Comment: What if i wanted to pass in a parameter to myFunc, how would i do that? thx

Comment: @kevinius you can simply declare your function with parameters. There's nothing magical about jQuery plugin functions; they're just functions. Think of jQuery functions like `.css()` or `.attr()`. Whether the function takes parameters or not is really a separate question from the chaining behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is added to jQuery (which allows for chaining)  it is referred to as a plugin and several things must be taken into consideration.  For example, is your function itself chainable?  Will your function work on a single element or multiple?  I would recommend that you research jQuery plugins and build your function as a plugin in jQuery.

Here is an [excellent tutorial](http://www.websanova.com/blog/jquery/the-ultimate-guide-to-writing-jquery-plugins#.Uu5_B7SV3FI) on building a jQuery plugin that covers concepts such as chaining, passing properties and calling different plugin functions.  Take a look at the article and determine if your function truly needs to be a plugin.

It may be better to simply pass `jQuery` and the selected elements as arguments to your function instead of chaining.

Comment: I think it's more userfriendly to let people initialise my script using a jquery method chaining pattern. That's why i'm not simply passing in jQuery to my plugin.

Comment: @kevinius There is no problem with that, but when you make that decision there are other items to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example:

```
var obj = {
    fn: function(){
        console.log("fn method");
        return this;
    },
    abc: function(){
        console.log("abc method");
        return this;
    },
    oneMore: function(){
        console.log("one more method");
        return this;
    }
};
```

Here chaining is provided by returning reference to **obj** Object.
Simply, every time you call a method on that object, you are returning that object - and you can continue calling its methods. This is basic chaining pattern that you can find in jQuery also  - slightly modified but the idea is same. Thanks to dynamic nature of javascript we can do this kind of things. Chaining allows coupling of related methods that are connected by common object. This pattern has its roots in functional programming, and javascript is heavily influenced by functional languages (mostly scheme).
But too much chaining can lead to unreadable code as can be seen in lot of jQuery examples.